# How to specify a default search period (eg of 1 year) in Roundcube?

Tags: web-hosting

Does anyone know if its practical to modify Roundcube to - by default - make searches scan over the previous 12 months?  (Maybe by editing config.inc.php ?)

I'm running roundcube 1.6.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is Web Applications a more relevant site for this?

Comment: @RohitGupta  Thanks for the thought.  Never heard of that SE before (but somehow I have a bit of cred there!).   I did  a search for Roundcube there and it didn't come up with much at all - and I could not even find an appropriate tag for my post.  Going by the available tags that site seems more designed for SaaS products like GSuite and Facebook.